# Creating a wizard-like application in C# 2008 - .net 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have been beating my head against the wall in an attempt to figure out how to create a wizard-like application in C# using Visual Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5 framework.

I have found other people asking for a solution to this same issue in older StackOverflow and forum posts, but the solutions provided are either pay-for solutions or are so far outdated I can't see a simple enough upgrade path to get it working 3.5.

I am looking for suggestions that meet the following criteria:

1. It must be free and redistributable
2. It must work with Visual Studio 2008
3. It must employ .Net 3.5
4. It must work with Winforms

I look forward to any answers this question receives.

Thanks!

Comment: How about rolling your own? Just have a form with prev/next/cancel and a switchable panel. It can't be that hard...

Comment: Jan, I was looking at taking that approach, but handling the prev/next/cancel logic and getting to the proper form in the stack is the trick. Also, if the wheel already exists, I'd rather know where to get it than to try and create my own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c)

Comment: You're right, Hans. Would you be willing to post that as an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Hans Passant and Jan de Vaan, there are already known ways of doing this. I ended up rolling my own solution and using the TabControl as suggested in [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c) and all is working well.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into the Microsoft MSDN?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y1368

The above link is an example walkthrough from the MSDN on how to create a wizard using built-in features.

I hope that helps.

Comment: From what I understand, those wizards are confined to just creating projects and objects within Visual Studio. What I need is actually an application that is a wizard itself.