# Using a button to go to another windows form

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, button, dialog

Okay I am probably going to get a load of down votes for this question as it is incredibly basic but I cannot seem to find my solution from googling it. I am using visual c++ 2005 .net and I am creating forms in the style of a wizard. I basically want a button to be clicked to get to the next form. The first form is Form1.h and the form I want it to go to is called Parts.h Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is the code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a new instance of the form you want to open, and then show it. You can do it by doing something like this:

```
 Form2 ^form2 = gcnew Form2();
 form2->ShowDialog();
```

Plus, you need to include the second form on the form that is going to open it.

Comment: Isn't this visual basic not visual c++?

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake. Although, the conversion to c++ should be pretty simple. Just create a new instance of your form, and then use the ShowDialog method to show it.