# How to hide a WinForms form without losing it's data

Tags: c#, winforms

i implement a wizard in c#, in this manner:

```
private static void MyInitialization()
{
   WizardData wData = new WizardData();
   wData.FormToShow = WizardData.wizardForms.FirstStep;
   Form step1 = new FirstStep(wData);
   Form step2 = new SecondStep(wData);
   Form step3 = new ThirdStep(wData);
   while (wData.FormToShow != WizardData.wizardForms.Cancel)
   {
     switch (wData.FormToShow)
     {
         case WizardData.wizardForms.FirstStep:
         {
              step1.ShowDialog();
              break;
         }
         case WizardData.wizardForms.SecondStep:
         {
             step2.ShowDialog();
             break;
         }
         case WizardData.wizardForms.ThirdStep:
         {
             step3.ShowDialog();
             break;
          }
      }
```

when i want to move to another form i need to close the `currnet(this.close),` but i want make the current `visibility=false` and not lose the data in the current form when i go to other form?

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // to show the SecondStep form
       wData.FormToShow = WizardData.wizardForms.SecondStep;
       this.Close();
}
```

any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Hide()` method

```
Form1.Hide();
```

This way, the Form won't be visible, and the data will be saved until you `Dispose()` of the form.

Comment: thanks,work fine, what can i do to avoid flickering between the forms?

Comment: What do you mean by flickering?

Comment: The transition between the form that hide() and the form that get the ShowDialog()instead.this transition not smooth.can i repair this? thanks.