# Issue with Panel visibility

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, layer

There are 3 panels pnlPanel0, pnlPanel1, pnlPanel2 with the same size and the same position.

With buttons "left" or "right"  I need to change visibility of each panel.

With pnlPanel0 (contains labels) and pnlPanel2 (contains buttons) - OK.

But with pnlPanel1 (contains ListView):

curLayer == 1: after pnlPanel1.Visible = true;
panel with ListView is still invisible.

But if pnlPanel1 is not intersected with pnlPanel0 and pnlPanel2 - OK.

Why?

May be in this case is something wrong with "Bring to front"/"Send to back"?

Is there another safe and issue-free solution?

```
     if (curLayer == 0)
        {
            pnlPanel0.Visible = true;
            pnlPanel1.Visible = false;
            pnlPanel2.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (curLayer == 1)
        {
            pnlPanel0.Visible = false;
            pnlPanel1.Visible = true;
            pnlPanel2.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (curLayer == 2)
        {
            pnlPanel0.Visible = false;
            pnlPanel1.Visible = false;
            pnlPanel2.Visible = true;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pnlPanel1.Visible)); // always false
```

.NET CF 3.5/WinForms/VS 2008/WinCE

Comment: Are you sure you haven't nested one panel inside another panel? If you have this situation, when you set the parent panel to Visible=False the nested panels will be invisible also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net panel visibility=true does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166319/net-panel-visibility-true-does-not-work)

Comment: OK, I try to solve problem without panel. There is some issue with background color in label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a form with about 7 Panel controls on it.

At `Form_Load`, all Panels are set to `.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`.

Further, all Panels share this same `GotFocus` event:

```
private void ActivePanel_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
  if (pnl != null) {
    pnl.BringToFront();
  }
}
```

Do you need to do something with a particular panel? OK, then take a look at this version:

```
private void ActivePanel_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
  if (pnl != null) {
    pnl.BringToFront();
    if (pnl.Name == pnlPanel0.Name) {
      // Do something with pnlPanel0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution:

make it without panels