# Set the visibility of separate GroupBoxes

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm using VB.Net and in one of my `WindowsForm` I have created 3 `GroupBox`es.

The problem is: I can't control `groupbox.visible = true/false;` so if I put the first `GroupBox` to `false` and the others to `true`... I still can't see the others.

I think I can't put one `GroupBox` on another group box, because when I do this, the overlapping group box will become the child of the below group box.

I have tried the `Panel` control but still have the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net panel visibility=true does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166319/net-panel-visibility-true-does-not-work)

Answer (score 2):

> I think I cant put one groupbox on another group box, because when I do this, the overlapping group box will become the child of the below group box.

Yes, that seems like the most likely explanation. Windows has a hard rule about visibility: when a *parent* control is hidden/invisible, all of its *children* will also be invisible. This applies equally to all controls, which explains why the Panel didn't work for you either.

So if you want to change this state of your group boxes independently, you will need to make sure that they're children only of your form, not of each other.

This can be a real pain to get right in the designer using the mouse. Instead, use the "Document Outline" window, which shows you the forms on your control in a TreeView that emphasizes the hierarchy. Make sure that all of the group box controls are at the same level in that tree.

Comment: +1 for "this can be a real pain to get right in the designer _using the mouse_" (emphasis added by me): It might be easier with the keyboard, since a control does not automatically become a child of another control with which it overlaps / on which it is placed. For example: **1.** Set each group box's final size. **2.** Place all group boxes such that they do not overlap anywhere. **3.** Move each group box to its final location by selecting it and moving it using the keyboard's arrow keys.

Comment: @stakx Also good advice. I generally just type the location into the Properties Window. Although more and more now I find myself avoiding the designer altogether except for rough mockups.

Comment: @user2550171: Since you're a fairly new SO member, may I suggest that you accept this answer if it solved your problem? Voting up an answer (using the upper triangle on the left side) is the SO's way of saying "thank you", accepting an answer (using the tick on the left) is SO's way of saying "this solved my problem / helped me the most". And both you and the answerer will earn points...