# Best way to "toggle" between two UserControls on a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created two separate `UserControls` and (depending on which `RadioButton` is selected) I would like one or the other to be displayed.

Right now, I simply dragged one instance of each `UserControl` onto the form and placed one on top of another (setting one `.Visible = false;`).

This is OK, but I was wondering if there was a better or more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly reasonable.

If you're concerned about keeping around resources you're no longer using, you can add a `Panel` and add or remove the control from there.

E.g.

```
try
{
    panel.SuspendLayout();
    panel.Controls.Remove(userControl1);
    panel.Controls.Add(userControl2);
}
finally
{
    panel.ResumeLayout();
}
```

If the user controls do things like connect to data sources, you might want to actually dispose and recreate them. Really depends on how complex the controls are. If they're just capturing a few properties, your current solution is fine.