# Switching between User Controls within a Form

Tags: c#

Tittle pretty much states it all. I have multiple user controls within a form and I'm trying to change between them on a button click.

What I've tried so far

```
UC1 openForm = new UC1();
UC1.Show();
Visible = false;
```

I also tried the bring to front method but had little success getting anywhere. If anyone has a better method to achieving this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you adding the User control programmatically? or are you okay with placing them in the designer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to "toggle" between two UserControls on a panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491627/best-way-to-toggle-between-two-usercontrols-on-a-panel)

Comment: How about using tablayout ? instead of using forms

Answer (score 0):

If you wish on button click to switch between only 2 controls then simply do,

```
if(ctlOne.Focused)
{
    ctlTwo.Focus();
    //OR
    ctlTwo.Select();
}
else
{
    ctlOne.Focus();
    //OR
    ctlOne.Select();
}
```

If you wish to switch between list of controls, then you can loop through all the controls in `Form` using,

```
foreach (Control c in frmAbc.Controls) 
{
    if(c.Focused)
    {
        //Set focus to desired control using Focus() OR Select();
    }
}
```