# Converted VB.NET app to C# and Can't Figure Out Where To Put Variable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I am making a tutorial program. It operates via pressing a button that moves you to the next step and another to go backwards. All the instructions are displayed using a Rich Text Box. The VB.NET version of the program used a select case to do everything and I simply declared the variable underneath

`Public Class Form1`

and then I could call it from any of the "button-presses" and have no issues. I can't do that in C# because it expects variables to be declared inside the contexts.

Comment: Can you post some actual C# code and what the actual error is?  C# most certainly can use class-level variables.

Comment: Visual Basic allows you to ignore object oriented programming principles, like Form1 can also be an object reference even though it is a type name.  That's just not possible in C#.  Unlearning VB.NET can be very difficult.  You'll need help from the books in your local library or a school.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HansPassant Unlearning VB can also be very valuable moving forward.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring class level members is very similar in both C# and VB.NET. Below is an example of a class level variable being declared and then incremented on a button click.

**VB.NET**

```
Public Class Form1

Private x as Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as Event Args) Handles Button1.Click

    x = x + 1

End Sub
```

**C#**

```
public class Form1
{
    private int x;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

If this doesn't fix your issue, post up some code.

Comment: Thanks! I am not at home so I can not test it now but as sson as I get home, I will test it out and see what it says. Excuse my horrible way of posting the code in the question (someone changed it). I couldnt understand the directions to do it correctly.