# looking for the term for this component and how to implement it in C# .net 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, web-applications

im not sure what this component is called. although i have seen it thousands of times in all kind of forms and wizards (see attached picture)

I need to implement it into a web form wizard im building in a C# web application.
does this component have a control in ASP.NET ? if not does anyone know of a third party tool that can be embedded into my wizard[image] ?
Thanks

just to be more clear.im referring to the part that has a multiple select list and can be selected and moved into  the right column and deselected back to the list using the buttons.(not the wizard)

Comment: which component u want to know? blue colored or whole new project wizard ?

Comment: i meant the whole new project wizard (the two select list with 2 columns and possibility to move items from select list to selected column and back)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: no, this is not about creating a wizard,i have that part figured out already. please look at the question more closely.

Answer (score 0):

take two list boxes, four buttons, when u clicks the button >, add selected itemof listbox1 to listbox2.

when clicks on button >>,then add all items of listbox1 to listbox2

when u clicks the button <, add selected itemof listbox2 to listbox1.
when clicks on button <<,then add all items of listbox2 to listbox1