# C# Windows Forms Aplication changing the "view"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a program and I'm stuck with one thing.
The idea is basic, but I cant find it online (probably not looking right). What I want is click a button and in the same window change everything that shows. For example create 2 different forms and when I click in some button the window keeps beeping the same but the form changed to the 2nd form. 
It's seams simple enough to do, but I cant manage to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You have options. You can show hide any form you want or you can create two placeholders on one form on top of each other. One is initially hidden another is not. Then you can just swap the visibility on each.

Comment: UserControls,build each with the desired controls and design,then depending on user choice display the right one,its one idea....

Comment: Have you tried a tab control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a TabControl withot Headers. For archieving that, you can hook into the tabcontrols WndProc method  and catch the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message. You can find an example code over here: http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/creating-wizard-using-windows-forms/

Comment: Looks like that blogger got the code from Hans: [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342320/719186)

Comment: Everyone could come up with that idea by him-/herself

Comment: Thanks, that helped! not quite what I had in mind, but it's a solution