# How to get all controls from a wizard by C#

Tags: c#

I want to get all controls from current active wizard. and put these controls into a List, when click "Next" the wizard will change to another wizard. and put all controls on the new wizard into List.

for example:
launch a setup wizard of a product. how can I get all controls on this wizard.
is there any C# method to get these controls information and input these controls information into a List<> class.

i do not know if "AutomationElement" in C# can implement

could you tell me how to do? thanks.

Comment: This question is not clear. Please show a relevant code sample and/or edit the question to be more specific about your problem

Comment: See [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2340566/719186)