# How to make Next/Previous wizard in the same form in windows forms C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, as shown in the photo I have form1 (main form) with 12 buttons and with 12 panels (each panel contains 10 buttons).

so form1 has panel1, panel2 ..... panel12 and each panel is controlled (show/hide) by one of those 12 buttons in form1 , I want when I click button1 panel1 shows up, click button2 panel2 shows up and panel1 hides, click button3 panel3 shows up and and panel2 hides ... and so on. I just want to show a panel at time and hide the others. I know how to play with show/hide panels but the problem is:

form1 has 12 buttons,12 panels each of which has 10 big buttons and this means I can not fit all this buttons and panels in form1 (no space) and I dont want to create new form for each panel (popup form). I want to do it like next/previous wizard.

Can you please help how to achieve this, is there any other ways/tools or idea to do it?
Thank you

[image: Photo]

Comment: Not sure I follow, are you essentially saying that you want to show/hide a panel depending on which of the main forms 12 buttons is pressed?

Comment: Can't you just use tab control instead of those panels? This seems like so much extra work for close to no benefit.

Comment: Daniel Casserly. yes exactly and I know how to do it but the problem is how to fit all those buttons and panels in one form. or is there other way to achieve it? thank you

Comment: Gnqz . I thought about tab control but tab control wont meet the requirement of the application which I am developing.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a usercontrol for each panel, place all the controls on the usercontrols and switch out the currently needed usercontrol in your main form on button click?

Comment: why not just have one panel with 12 buttons, and change captions, handlers, etc. dynamically as the conceptual panel changes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp/2342320#2342320

Comment: Hi  Martin  . yes it is a good option. I had a look at Usercontrols and I created form1 with button1 and botton2 and also created Usercontrol1 and Usercontrol2 and . now in form1 I want to call Usercontrol1 when button1 is pressed and then press button2 to show Usercontrol2  and hide Usercontrol1 but I dont know how to do it. I created an object for Usercontrol1 (Usercontrol1.visible = true) but it didnt work. please help. thank you

Comment: Hi NDJ. yes I can consider this option but can you please explain more about what steps to follow? thank you