# Disable switching between tabs by click or keys in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

[image]

So guys, is it possible to switch to another tab by ONLY using NEXT button?

This is mean that you CAN'T switch to another tab page by clicking that other tab.

The code that I usually use on the NEXT button are something like this :

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
```

Comment: Is this the [tag:wpf] TabControl? Or the [tag:winforms] TabControl?

Comment: It's winforms, I still not familiar with what you ask, I guess that is winforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `ControlStyles.UserMouse` to true. This way you can simply disable mouse on tab headers.

By the way, just disabling click on headers is not enough and you need to disable keys which let the user to switch to between tabs, like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    public MyTabControl()
    {
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        var filteredKeys = new Keys[]{(Keys.Control | Keys.Tab),
            (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab),
            Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Home, Keys.End};
        if (filteredKeys.Contains(keyData))
            return true;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you like to have a wizard-like control (tab control without header), you can handle `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342320/3110834). You should disable those keys also in that solution too. Here is a changed version:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class WizardControl: TabControl
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        var filteredKeys = new Keys[]{(Keys.Control | Keys.Tab),
            (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab),
            Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Home, Keys.End};
        if (filteredKeys.Contains(keyData))
            return true;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    public const int TCM_FIRST = 0x1300;
    public const int TCM_ADJUSTRECT = (TCM_FIRST + 40);
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == TCM_ADJUSTRECT && !DesignMode)
           m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        else 
           base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put your code? Especially on => public class MyTabControl : TabControl. Should I create a new class named "MyTabControl" and inheriite it from TabControl?

Comment: Yest it's a new class. It's enough to copy the code and paste it in a new file in your project and after building the project the control will be added to ToolBox. Then you can drop an instance of the control on your form.

Comment: You can see the difference between the first one `MyTabControl` and the second one `WizardControl` at run-time. At design time, both of them are like standard `TabControl`, but at run-time, `WizardControl` doesn't show tab headers. It will act like a multi-panel which let you at design time work with all tab pages but at run-time you can just switch between tabs using code, like what is expected from a wizard. `MyTabControl` at rum-time is like a normal `TabControl` with header but to switch between tabs you should use code (for example click event of a button to set selected tab).

Answer (score 14):

TabControls `Selecting` Event will disable switching, but we need to keep track of button's `click` with a `bool` value, otherwise button's `click` won't select the tab either.

```
bool checkCancel = true;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkCancel = false;
    tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
}

private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = checkCancel;
    checkCancel = true;
}
```

**Result,** (btw trying to click to tabpages at the gif :))

[image]

Comment: This looks "clean" when there is no content in the tabs. However, when I set e.Cancel = true, the NEXT tab get is "flashed" at me before it cancels back to the original tab.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try on this

```
tabControl1.SelectTab(tabPage2);
```

On Index

```
tabControl1.SelectTab(1);
```

Tablist is 0 based index so "1" is the second tab.

Answer (score -1):

One of the options is to try simple `IsHitTestVisible="False"`

Comment: Needs more details.  TabControl and TabPage do not have a "IsHitTestVisible" property