# can we open second form on same window of first form in .Net windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Can we open second form on first form's window (hiding first form ) in windows form (.net c#) ???
Detailed problem:  suppose I have Form-A. Form-A has next button on click of which I want to open Form-B (on same window, hiding Form-A)
Also on Form-B, I can have back button on click of which we will get previous form (Form-A in this case).

I found this in MS access. Can we implement same in .Net windows form???

Comment: So you want to make a wizard dialog ?

Comment: Form has a `Hide` method but you may also want to consider using some `UseControl`s to load different pages of the wizard in the same form. You can also take advantage of a tab control which doesn't show tab headers as container for wizard pages. You can see such control [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342320/3110834) or a bit enhanced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40633229/3110834).

Comment: if you want to make wizard dialog, it's better to use from `UserControl`.
Nevertheless, in the `Form`, you can to use `Hide` and `Show` Methods in `Form`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you'd like to do this with multiple different `Forms`?

With `WinForms` you could achieve this like when click next, you hide your current form, let it be `FormA` and show the other form, let it be `FormB` at `FormA`'s position.

```
private void buttonNext_FormA(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  frmB.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
  frmB.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y);
  frmB.Show();
}

private void buttonBack_FormB(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  frmA.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
  frmA.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y);
  frmA.Show();
}
```

A little different but a general solution for navigation *next-back-next* is the `TabControl`:
Place a `TabControl` to your `Form`, place **Next** and **Back** `Buttons` below it. You can add multiple `Tabs` to your `TabControl` and you can place any `Control` inside your `Tabs` that you could put on a `Form`.
(To hide Tab headers, set the following properties):

```
tabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
tabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
tabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

**Subscribe** Back button click and Next button click event like this:

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (tabControl.SelectedIndex > 0)
    tabControl.SelectedIndex--;
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(tabControl.SelectedIndex < tabControl1.TabPages.Count)
    tabControl.SelectedIndex++;
}
```

But you could achieve this by **WPF**(**Windows Presentation Foundation**) [NavigationWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow?view=netframework-4.8), that's also a cool technology and it's made exactly for this purpose. 
There is a little tutorial ad MSDN for implement navigation window: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application)

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate forms, so what you can do is:

- When clicking the `Next` button in `Form-A`, `Form-B` is shown and `Form-A` is hidden.
- When clicking the `Previous` button in `Form-B`, exactly the opposite happens.

This can be easily achieved using the `Show` and `Hide` methods of Forms.

- In Next button click event handler:

```cs
this.Hide();
FormB.Show();
```

- In Previous button click event handler:

```cs
this.Hide();
FormA.Show();
```