# Disable a Tab in tabControl in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

**I am using C# 11 and .NET 7 with WinForm.**

I'm trying to disable tabPages of a tabControl.

1- I can not find an option to disable tabPages.

2- Nothing appears like tabPage1.Enable.

3- I would like to disable all the tabPages at the beginning of form load and then, enable one by one, depending on certain conditions in the previous tab or user inputs.

Comment: _"An option to disable a tab does not appear"_ - appear _where_ ?

Comment: [`TabPage.Enabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabpage.enabled?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) doesn't seem to be going anywhere?

Comment: @Fildor, that will disable the TabPage but it doesn't affect the tab, which is part of the TabControl. It's basically like disabling a Panel on a form, which a TabPage is.

Comment: Ah, the "handle" thing is not affected, you mean @jmcilhinney ? I guess I haven't been working with Winforms in a while...

Comment: There's nothing built into the standard TabPage or TabControl to do that. To learn how to customise the control to support it, check out [this site](https://dotnetrix.co.uk/).

Comment: For the record, the reason it's not supported out of the box is that Microsoft will tell you that the tab shouldn't be there at all if the user can't select it. It's very simple to add and remove TabPages so you should consider that option.

Comment: @ReyLo Maybe you should explain what _you_ consider "enabledd" and "disabled".

Comment: I'd have to test to confirm but I think that you can also set the width of a tab to be zero, so the tab is effectively hidden without removing the TabPage.

Comment: @Fildor Sorry, i am a Junior developer. If you like that nobody access a control, you can disable or readonly. My purpose is: I have 5 tabs enabled when the form is load. I need to maintain the first tab enable and the others disable (user can see the tabs not access) when load. Then, when the user complete the requirements of the texbox fields in the tab and press the button next (or save, submit, etc), in the first tabpage, if the conditions are fulfilled, the user can see the other tabpage2. Finally, in the tabpage5, the user can navigate between tabs because all the tabpages are enabled.

Comment: That sounds like a misuse of a TabControl as some sort of Wizard. Should a disabled Tabpage still be navigatable to or just visualized (The Tab but not the Page belonging to the Tab).

Comment: I see a lot of suggestions like: tabpage1.enable = false; or tabControl1.TabPages[1].Enabled = false; and others. But now this don't exist in the tabPage. Only tabControl1 have the enable option, not the tabPages...

Comment: Ok... I got it... I find enable inside a conditional. In the event of tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged,
If (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1) 
{ 
tabPage1.Enable = false; 
}

Comment: [Disable switching between tabs by click or keys in TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40630281/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Hey thanks. This is a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can not access the tab content**

```
private bool tabPage1CanNotBeSelected = true;

private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
      // Check the condition under which you want to restrict the selection.
      if (e.TabPage == tabPage1 && tabPage1CanNotBeSelected) 
      {
          e.Cancel = true; // Cancel the selection.
      }
}
```

**Additionally, if you need to see the content of the tab but disabled:**

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1 && tabPage1CanNotBeSelected)
    {
        tabPage1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LarsTech Fixed...  tabPage1 not tabControl1 

Thanks...