# Adding another page to windows form application - c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am quite new to C#. I am creating a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio 2017 and I was wondering how I link one page to another? e.g. clicking on next which will guide the user to the next page. I do not know the exact words for how to explain this but my research as of now has been quite useless.

I would like to know if I need to create another form? or simply add a new item to the existing form.. I am just not sure. Any help would be great thank you.

Sorry if unclear: E.g.

I have a form I am creating, which requires several details which should be on different stages of the app? I am wanting to have a next button which moves the user from the first page where it may have textboxes to a next page (which I will create - depending on how it works) where there may be radioButton questions.

Comment: How can you link one form to another, if you just have one. Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: You should search for Wizard forms. This is off-topic here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

If you want to project the new page in separate dialog or window just create **separate form** and trigger the open function of the form when next button is clicked.
If you want to project the new page in the same dialog then use **tab control** in that same form and make some validation to switch to next tab when next button is clicked.
**Note:** Using **tab control** is the best idea for your case.