# Replace panels with other items

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use a c# program with SQL so that I can make a database user interface.

The problem is that I have one form with a lot of panels so the question is, how can I use forms and still have one single window instead of a lot of pop-ups or a lot of panels inside each other in my main window?

I want to find another structure or type that replaces the panel but it is autonomous and does not make so much window form gore.

I tried putting a lot of forms but that just makes a lot of pop-ups and I only want one window.

[image]

Comment: Tried using [tabs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)? This is a vague question though, maybe [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47940758/edit) your answer to include a a picture of what you have and a mockup of what you'd like.

Comment: You can have panels inside panels.  So I would make the main form contain  one large panels and then pub all you other controls inside the main panel.

Comment: yeah i tried but i want to switch between them using buttons and verification of credentials not by those top buttons, thanks.

Comment: You could always separate your different panels into separate user controls (I'm assume you're using WinForms here)

Comment: See [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2340566/719186)

Comment: Lots of popups vs one window - alright, but what do you *need* to show *at the same time*? You can save lots of screen real estate simply by *temporarily hiding* things that are not relevant for the current activity. Imagine having add/delete/edit buttons and textboxes with details name/surname/family/shoesize. When you press "add", textboxes are needed to enter new data. But the buttons thdmselves are not needed anymore, you can get rid of them (hide,etc) to save space and show them back once entering new data is finished. And so on. Start with analyzing what do you NEED to show and WHEN.